# How to associate a checkbox with a dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net

I have a checkbox and dropdown list in my interface. I try to do the following: Initially dropdown list is disabled. When a checkbox is clicked, the dropdown list becomes enabled, then if clicked again it becomes disabled again and so on. Here is the code:

```
 protected void cbPreq1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (cbPreq1.Checked)
        dPrereq1.Enabled = true;  //enable dropdown list
    else
        dPrereq1.Enabled = false; //disable dropdown list
}
```

But the problem is, we never enter to this function when i debugged. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AutoPostback="True"` in your markup for `<asp:CheckBox ID="cbPreq1" runat="server" />`